# React-navigation: detect new screen is fully focused

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

With current version of react-navigation, there are two ways to check if a screen is focused or not, by either (1) calling function `isFocused` of screen's prop `navigation`, or (2) hook the component to `withNavigationFocused` and retrieve prop `isFocused`.

However, both methods always return true when navigation starts. In my case, I need something triggering only when screen transition ends, i.e. new screen is fully focused. This is to deal with heavy-rendered children, such as camera or map, which should be rendered after screen transition to avoid slow transition animation.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try subscribing to the navigation lifecycle events, as described in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle):

```
const didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didFocus',
  payload => {
    console.debug('didFocus', payload);
  }
);
```

Another example usage in this [repo](https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-backhandler/blob/master/BackHandler.android.js)

Comment: Work great! Thanks for your solution

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm trying to use it to trigger animation, and part of the problem is that I can't use Animated in my case, I can only do it via LayoutAnimation. The didFocus callback gets called after the render function but BEFORE the content actually appears on screen. I checked this by putting a debugger statement inside - execution stops during a blank screen. As a result, LayoutAnimation gets applied to the whole screen, not just my particular animation. Any ideas how to defer the callback until the screen actually appears?

Comment: @dols3m LayoutAnimation always applies to the whole screen.

Comment: @vonovak As far as I know, it applies to whatever re-render happens after you call configureNext. If the whole screen is re-rendered - yes, it applies to the whole screen. However, I am trying to make sure it gets called after the whole screen becomes visible, so that animation applies only to the element I update after that. More specifically, I'm trying to resize a header with a spring animation. Instead, the whole screen springs into view.

Comment: You can listen to the `focus` event instead of the `willFocus` or `didFocus` events for the 4.x version of the react-navigation library.