# How to deal with state during a screen transition using react native and react navigation

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am getting an object undefined exception during a transition from one screen to another. I have a pretty good idea what is happening, I am just not sure if there is a clean way of handling it without just checking for undefined everywhere.

Here is my scenario:

1. Source screen references a user object in a Redux store
2. Navigation is initiated from the source screen to the destination screen.
3. The destination screen componentDidMount() is called where I clear the user object from the Redux store.
4. The source screen render() gets called again and the undefined error occurs because I cleared user from the store.

I am assuming that the source and destination screens have some overlap due to the transition. I have tried adding listeners with no luck. I can only get listener handlers to fire for type = action,

I am probably making this more complicated than it is, but I would like to find out if there is a standard way of dealing with this or if I am going about it in a completely wrong way.

Also, my react-navigation is integrated with Redux as per the instructions on React Navigation's website and the Redux React Navigation sample code.

Here is the basic code.

Screen 1

```
componentDidMount() {
  // This is a Redux action that sets an object called user to null
  clearUser();
{
```

Screen 2

```
render() {
  return (
    // Other code here
    // user is null here because render gets called after Screen1#componentDidMount() gets called
    <Text>{user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.dispatch({ type:'NAV_SCREEN_1' })}
    >
      // button code here
    </TouchableOpacity>
    // Other code here
  )
}
```

The type of error is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null"

I understand the error and why I am getting it. The user object has been set to null by my Redux action in componentDidMount() of Screen 1 and then Redux causes render of Screen 2 to get called which is referencing a user object which is null.

My question is, is there a special way to accommodate this behavior without having to check if the user object is null every place I need to use it ? Should I call clearUser() somewhere else ?

Comment: There are too many different things that could be happening for anyone to guess. Please post example code that is the minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem, and the specific error message, if you want help.

Comment: @stone I have edited my question.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027713/react-navigation-detect-new-screen-is-fully-focused/50029287#50029287. Make use of blur and focus events to trigger your function

Comment: @ThoVu I am using an older version of react-navigation that hasn't implemented addListener yet. I will go through and try to get all my packages updated to the latest versions possible and see if I have access to addListener and try it out. - Thanks

Comment: @ThoVu Put your comment up as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the newest version of `react-navigation`, you can use either [addListener](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle), [withNavigationFocus](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/with-navigation-focus.html#docsNav) or [isFocused](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#isfocused-query-the-focused-state-of-the-screen) to detect transition state of the screens.

Another unofficial way is to catch action type `NavigationActions.COMPLETE_TRANSITION`, in case of using middleware like `redux-saga`.

Comment: Thanks @ThoVu It makes sense to do it this way. The screen I am navigating to is a log In screen. Wait till it has complete focus then delete the user.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can simply make your Redux-connected screen handle undefined or null state. I had a similar problem and I ended up rendering a loader instead of the screen content when user state is undefined. When I log out, the screen shows a loader for a fraction of a second, then the app navigates away.